# Exclamation mark in data declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell

What does the exclamation mark mean in this Haskell data declaration:

```
data Sample = First !Integer | Second !String
```

Comment: It's a bang pattern. It means that the construct is string, so that `First undefined == undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes this field *strict* - [see here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Data_types#Strict_fields)

if you add this to the field you make sure that the value is evaluated when you use the constructor - it's usually helpful to avoid space-leaks (from a huge thunk-chain)

if you use GHC8 you can have this by default if you use the [`Strict` or `StrictData` pragma](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/StrictPragma)